# Solace NIFI JMSConnectionFactoryProvider

Tags: apache-nifi, solace

I am trying to connect to Solace Queues on a VPN different then default using Appache NIFI ConsumeJMS Processor. When I try to enable the JMSConnectionFactoryProvider I get the following error:

> JMSConnectionFactoryProvider Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method due to
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Failed to load and/or instantiate class
>   'com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnectionFactory'

The NIFI JMSConnectionFactoryProvider provides a generic service to create vendor specific javax.jms.ConnectionFactory implementations. ConnectionFactory can be served once this service is configured successfully.

Why is NIFI Unable to find the class within the Solace JMS API Jar files?

Comment: There's not enough information in that single line to determine why Apache-NiFi cannot load Solace's JMS ConnectionFactory. Possible errors can range from the class not being found in your classpath, to an configuration error. The best way to determine the root cause is to enable Solace API logs, and provide more details. Details on how to enable the Solace API logs can be found over at http://docs.solace.com/Solace-JMS-API/Code-and-Compile-Guideli.htm

Comment: Looking deeper into the NiFi Logs I see this:

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnectionFactory.<init>()
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 ... 18 common frames omitted

Comment: There is no `com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnectionFactory.<init>` method. Do you know how is the Solace JMS connection factory being created?

Comment: Here is what I can find: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-jms-bundle/nifi-jms-cf-service/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/jms/cf/JMSConnectionFactoryProvider.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

----- Update --------

Solace JMS API 10.1.0 now contains an zero argument default constructor, and integration with NiFi is now possible.

Here is an example configuration:

1. Controller: 
   [image: Controller Configuration]]

The MQ ConnectionFactory Implementation is set to `com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnectionFactoryImpl`.

2. ConsumeJMS Processor:
   [image: ConsumeJMS Processor]

Username field can also take the form of "myUsername@myMessageVPN".

----- Original -------

The problem here is that Apache NiFi is not using a portable method of creating a `ConnectionFactory`. It is trying to create a `ConnectionFactory` by calling an zero argument default constructor, but there's no guarantee that one exists.

```
// From https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-jms-bundle/nifi-jms-cf-service/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/jms/cf/JMSConnectionFactoryProvider.java
private void createConnectionFactoryInstance(ConfigurationContext context) {
    String connectionFactoryImplName = context.getProperty(CONNECTION_FACTORY_IMPL).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue();
    this.connectionFactory = Utils.newDefaultInstance(connectionFactoryImplName);
}
```

Note that there's an entry over at NiFi's JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2701 to "Add JNDI Factory support for JMS ConnectionFactory service". (The initial description of that entry is a bit confusing, but the comments are clearer.)

At this point, Solace only supports the creation of the `ConnectionFactory` through the standard JNDI lookup - `javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup()` and through Solace's proprietary method - `SolJmsUtility.createConnectionFactory()`.

Solace will investigate whether it is feasible to implement a zero argument default constructor for the `ConnectionFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

A JNDI connection provider is developed and published at http://dev.solace.com/integration-guides/nifi/. For people that are interested in this provider, it is worthwhile finding out.

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you, I had created the same thing but realized that the NIFI JMS Consumer is not a listener which fails to meet the requirements for us. I need to develop an entire new processor to provide a JMS Listener.